# Is there any way to undo after clearing a log on Windows 2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-event-log, eventviewer

I accidentally cleared a event log. Is there any way I can get it back?

Comment: Restore it from backup.

Comment: So Windows server 2008 backs up all the events from the past somewhere?

Comment: @Duk: No, *you* back up your important data. If you don't, it's not important data by definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are gone, unless you either:

- Saved the logs as it suggested you do when you clicked clear
- Have a full system backup

It's also possible but unlikely data recovery software could undelete them.  They are stored in C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs if you want to use software like GetDataBack or similar to try to recover them.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the event logs are stored in `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs`.  As ErkiA eludes to, restoring from backup maybe your only option.  This is assuming you do a full system backup with somehthing like Backup Exec.

The only other saving grace is if you have Volume Shadow Copy on your Primary Drive.  But still, this **requires some source which you are actively backing up.**